# Calling object more than once

Tags: javascript

Hello I have code which replaces `document.write`, makes a buffer and than pushes buffer into the document:

```
  var lazyLoad = {

    url: '',
    block: '',
    buffer: '',

    init: function(url,block){
        that = this
        that.url = url;
        that.block = block;

        console.info(this.block)
        console.log(this.url)

        window.d = document
        window.onload = function(){
            that.work()
        }   
    },

    work: function(){
        that = this
        d.write = d.writeln = function(s){ 
                                    that.buffer += s
                                }
        d.open = d.close = function(){}
        s = d.createElement('script');       
        s.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');
        s.setAttribute('src',that.url);
        d.getElementById(that.block).appendChild(s)
        s.onload = function () {
            window.setTimeout(function() {

                console.warn(that.block + ' ' +that.buffer)
                d.getElementById(that.block).innerHTML += that.buffer;
                that.buffer = '';
            }, 0);
       }
    }
}
```

If I init it once:

```
lazyLoad.init(
        'http://test.com/test.js',              
         div1
)
```

But if I call it again with other parameters:

```
lazyLoad.init(
        'http://test2.com/test.js',             
         div2
)
```

First init wont work. `window.buffer` will be empty. Where is my mistake?

P.S. another problem: I tried to replace `window.onload` with jQuery method `$(window).load()` but it fires twice. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

basically, you have only one buffer: **window.buffer**, if you call the **init()** twice, the window.buffer will be manipulated by the second call, while the first call might not complete. **I'd recommend you use a seperate buffer for every init(). which can essentially avoid this issue.**

For your second question,

```
window.onload != $(window).load()
```

window.onload will only execute the method you last assign to it, while $(window).load() maintains a chain, you can **init()** twice, then there are two methods in the chain.

Comment: ok, i changed my buffer, update post, but still it works only on second init. on first - nothing happens

Comment: you still only have one buffer, which is **lazyload.buffer** now, you can use an array to store the buffer for each call.

Comment: or an easier solution is: every time you use a new **lazyload** object to **init()**

Comment: "or an easier solution is: every time you use a new lazyload object to init() " what do you mean?